# Spatial tensor product of operator spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, operator-algebras

If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $\otimes_\varepsilon$ denotes the injective tensor product, then in general $\otimes_\varepsilon$ does not respect quotients unless we map into $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-spaces. To be more precise, if $W,Z$ are $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-spaces and $T\colon X\to W$, $S\colon Y\to Z$ are quotient maps then so is $T\otimes S$.

Now my question is: does a something similar hold for the spatial (injective) tensor product of operator spaces? The class replacing $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-spaces is presumably the class of nuclear operator spaces.

Comment: I don't think nuclear operators is a good substitute for $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-space. I think it should be somewhat $\mathcal{B}(H)$. But.... There was a work on generalization of the notion of $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-spaces for $C^*$-algebras. It turns out that such $C^*$ ameanable. Note that $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is not amenable, so I don't even know what operator space you substitute instead of $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-space.

Comment: Nuclear operator spaces, not nuclear operators!

Comment: Clearly, it is enough to prove the fact for operators of the form $1_X\otimes T$, where $X$ is nuclear. Using local techniques, I believe, from 4.4 in Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals. A. Defant, K. Floret you can reduce your problem to the case $X=M_n$. Also I recommend you to take a look at On OL_infty structure of nuclear C-star-algebras. M. Junge, N. Ozawa, Z.J. Ruan